# No Command Error on Nexus 5X, even in recovery mode

Tags: nexus-5x

I used Wugfresh' root installer before and it worked like a charm. You can't get any OTA's with it though. Since I wanted Android 7, I wanted to unroot, install the OTA and reroot using Wugfresh' client. I already did this before when I wanted to upgrade to Android 6. Then everything went well and I was done in an hour.

This time however, I'm stuck. When it needed to reboot after succesfully installing Android 7.1.1, I got set to the No Command screen. After some googling I found out that you had to go to the bootloader first, and then go to Recovery. I got that far, but now I have no clue on what to do.

Rebooting from there doesn't work (obviously). It seems logical to me that I have to install TWRP, but the zip file is not there anymore to install it. Is there a way to still get this zip file on my phone while in recovery mode, and is this the solution to my problem? I also found the format option in TWRP. Does that get rid of all the TWRP stuff and bring me back to complete stock, so I can go back to rooting everything again? I'd be happy to do so, since right now I'm sitting with nothing but a dead Android.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: is adb working?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Connect the phone to your computer while in Recovery mode and run `adb`, which of course you'll need to have installed from the Android SDK Tools.  It sounds like you'll need to flash a ROM from Fastboot, though.

Comment: ADB is working, but I have no clue on what to do with that.

Comment: @Arno you can put files from your PC via adb so put your zip file

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest [TWRP image](https://dl.twrp.me/bullhead/).
2. Download [Android SDK platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) and extract the zip file.
3. Move the TWRP image inside `platform-tools` folder.
4. Boot your phone into bootloader (keep holding volume up + volume down + power until you see the bootloader screen).
5. Connect your phone to PC / laptop via USB cable.
6. Navigate to `platorm-tools` folder which was extracted on PC / laptop.
7. Hold shift and right click inside empty space in the folder and click `Open command windows here`.
8. Type `fastboot devices` and press enter. You should see your device being listed.
9. Type `fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.1-0-bullhead.img` and press enter. It should finish flashing in a few seconds.
10. Press volume down two times on your phone to select `Recovery`.
11. Press power button and it should boot to TWRP recovery.